# Change moment timezone not reflecting to .toDate()

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

[Ngx Bootstrap Datepicker](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/tree/development/src/datepicker) returns a JS Date object.

I have a custom Time picker that returns a string formatted as `HH:mm`.

What I need to do right now is to create a JS Date object with the selected Date, selected Time and a specific TimeZone.

I'm trying to use moment (cause we use that for dates in the whole application) but I'm having not expected behaviours.

I'm trying to:

```
const specificMoment = moment.tz(date, timeZone); // date is the Ngx Bootstrap selected date
specificMoment.set('hour', +time.split(':')[0]); // time is HH:mm string
specificMoment.set('minute', +time.split(':')[1]);
return specificMoment.toDate
```

*`timeZone` changes according to the user, not due to it's browser, it's an attribute of the user, so I can't set `moment.tz.setDefault(...);`.

What I'm facing is that `.toDate` is returning my current timeZone, event though it appears my different timeZone inside the moment object.
[image]

Why is it working like this and what would be a working implementation for what I need?

Ps: `console.log(specificMoment.format());` returns wrong timeZone as well `2018-12-20T23:00:30-02:00`.

**EDIT**

Turns out using 
`const specificMoment = moment(date).tz(timeZone);` 
and then 
`return specificMoment.toDate()` 
"works". It returns a Date object with `2018-12-21T05:00:00.323-0200`, which is the date with specified timezone (GMT -8:00) but displayed on my current timezone (GMT -2:00).
The data is stored on my DB correctly.
Can someone explain why?

Thx.

Comment: Date objects *can not* be in a specific time zone.  Moment has no magic there. You can  produce a string with the correct time zone using the `format` function, but Date objects will always be UTC based internally, and show local time externally.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't setup moment-timezone with any data about the timezone to use.
Check out this link on [Data Loading](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/) in momentjs.

I've created a JS Bin for your example that shows how to use Data Loading.  Check it out [here](https://jsbin.com/mufoyeh/4/edit?js,console).
e.g.

```
moment.tz.add([
    'America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|0101|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0',
    'America/New_York|EST EDT|50 40|0101|1Lz50 1zb0 Op0'
]);
```